# Illegal string offset - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Desde hace unos días estamos recibiendo el siguiente mensaje de error en el backoffice de nuestra web creada con wordpress:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'custom_css_post_id' in /usr/home/xxxxxxxxx/web/wp-includes/theme.php on line 1059
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'et_pb_css_synced' in /usr/home/xxxxxxxxx/web/wp-includes/theme.php on line 1059"

La línea referida es la siguiente:

```
$mods[ $name ] = apply_filters( "pre_set_theme_mod_{$name}", $value, $old_value );
```

Dentro de la función set_theme_mod:

```
function set_theme_mod( $name, $value ) {
$mods      = get_theme_mods();
$old_value = isset( $mods[ $name ] ) ? $mods[ $name ] : false;

/**
 * Filters the theme modification, or 'theme_mod', value on save.
 *
 * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$name`, refers to the key name
 * of the modification array. For example, 'header_textcolor', 'header_image',
 * and so on depending on the theme options.
 *
 * @since 3.9.0
 *
 * @param string $value     The new value of the theme modification.
 * @param string $old_value The current value of the theme modification.
 */
$mods[ $name ] = apply_filters( "pre_set_theme_mod_{$name}", $value, $old_value );

$theme = get_option( 'stylesheet' );
update_option( "theme_mods_$theme", $mods );}
```

Cualquier ayuda sería bienvenida.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque hace referencia a un archivo interno de wordpress parece que en realidad el error es debido a un conflicto interno entre un tema y un plugin, testee un poco para verificar si es así, desactive todos los plugin y active uno a uno para verificar si el error persiste, también pruebe a desactivar el tema.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta Jefferzon, eso ya lo probé sin éxito.

Comment: Verifica la versión de php que tienes, si aun usas php 5 actualiza a 7, puede que ese sea el problema

Comment: Ya tenemos php 7